# Sending a parameter to a GridView using SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am new to Visual Studio, coming from Delphi.

I have a `GridVew`, linked to a `SqlDataSource`, which works fine if not filtered.

When I try to filter it, I get nothing.

These are my `SelectParameters`:

```
 <SelectParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblPropertyName" DbType="String" DefaultValue="" Name="strPropertyName" PropertyName="Text" />
</SelectParameters>
```

In the code-behind, in `Page_Load`, I get the value that I want the Grid filtered by:

```
lblPropertyName.Text = strPropertyName;
```

Cannot seem to get the `GridView` filtered, as it brings up nothing.

Can someone take the time to help me out in this?

Edited code added from your comment

In the Source page:

```
<SelectParameters> 
      <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblPropertyName" DbType="String" DefaultValue="" Name="strPropertyName" PropertyName="Text" /> 
</SelectParameters>
```

IN CODE BEHIND:

```
foreach (string propertyName in result) 
{ 
   strPropertyName = propertyName; 
}
 lblPropertyName.Text = strPropertyName;
```

Comment: have you looked at MSDN for examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selectparameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: where is the DataSource that you are attempting to attach this to..? show all relevant code please

Comment: I am trying to show the code, it's too long, but will figure it out.

Comment: really..then why not show the code

Comment: In the Source page:     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblPropertyName" DbType="String" DefaultValue="" Name="strPropertyName" PropertyName="Text" /> IN CODE BEHIND:    
            foreach (string propertyName in result)
            {
                strPropertyName = propertyName;
            }
            lblPropertyName.Text = strPropertyName;
    </SelectParameters>

Comment: sorry, not sure how to get the code you need on here.

Comment: same place you put the code in your original question edit your question and paste it there..

Comment: I am so sorry, It will not allow me to paste the code!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try like this :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Table_1 where [col1]=@col">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label1" Name="col" PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```